# Why is there an extra space at the right of my site?

Tags: css

On my site when you shrink the browser and scroll to the right side appears some extra space.

I have a background image set as `background1`, and the `background2` and `background3` don't cover the whole width.

Here is the link to my site: http://www.iupui.edu/~streamit/N315/paigwhit/projectFiles/index2.html

Answer (score 2):

On your background2 and pagejump2 classes you have `width: 110%` - make that `width: 100%` and that should work

```
#background2 {
 background-color: #666;
 height: 600px;
 width: 100%;  /* changed to 100% */
 margin-right: 0px;
 z-index: 2;
 color: #fff;
 text-align: center;
 font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
 background-image: url(images/dots.png);
 background-repeat: repeat;
 min-width: 1000px;
}

#pagejump2 {
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%; /* changed to 100% */
  background-color: #98bee0;
  padding-bottom: 1px;
  background-image: url(images/dots.png);
  background-repeat: repeat;
}
```

Comment: And it'll need to be done for `#pagejump2` too.

Comment: @davidpauljunior - yes you're right. I'll add that to the answer. Thanks.